# How can I access email id's of my facebook friends

Tags: facebook-graph-api, koala

I am using koala(ruby gem/Facebook Api).

I want to access email list of my Facebook friend's.

Contacts (mac app) can access my friend's email id and their mobile phone no's.

How can I do that???

Answer (score 0):

I don't particularly program with the facebook api.  I wouldn't think they would provide you with direct access to information not published.  Most sights such as Google (gmail) and Yahoo provide email addresses for their users that is associated with their username.

Facebook does also.  Just use their public.username@facebook.com, just as you would a person's username@yahoo.com or their username@gmail.com.

Comment: yes. But I cannot send message to someone's facebook id with my email server.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
fb_api = Koala::Facebook::API.new(access_token)
fb_api.api("me/friends?fields=email")
```

but not every user will have entered the email address